# JSON returning multidimensional arrays from cryptcompare api

Tags: json, google-sheets-api, cryptoapi

I have been trying to figure out how to get data from JSON from cryptocompare api to google spreadsheet.Here it's my code:

```
function gather(symbol, array) {
for (i in array.AggregatedData) {
return array[i];
  }
return 0;
}

function chc(symbol, key, rand) {
var url = "https://www.cryptocompare.com/api/data/coinsnapshot/?fsym="+ symbol +"&tsym=USD";

var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
var text = response.getContentText();

var obj_array = JSON.parse(text);
var obj = gather(obj_array);
var value = obj[key];

return parseFloat(value);
}
```

I get an error that cannot read the property of AggregatedData undefined.

Here it's the way the data shows on the api 
[JSON output](https://www.cryptocompare.com/api/data/coinsnapshot/?fsym=BTC&tsym=USD)

Answer (score 0):

You might have a wrong variable type.

If AggregatedData is method or function you should use () at the end.

PS: There is a script from Trevor Lohrbeer that can be used to import JSON more intuitively.